# Hidden Whitespace Best Practice

Tags: coding-style, whitespace

I think most people agree that trailing whitespace is not good practice. A lot of editors will display it for you or automatically strip it out.

Consider this Python function as a simple example:

[image: Whitespace Example Screenshot]

The extra whitespace on lines 11 and 13 are wrong. What I'm wondering about is line 10. Should a blank line inside a control block that doesn't change indentation have leading whitespace?

Most editors I've used will keep the cursor at the indentation level from the preceding line, so making a blank line without leading whitespace takes some extra formatting. What's the best practice? Should line 10 have leading whitespace or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question sticking to your Python example, quoting their style guide.

From [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements):

> Method definitions inside a class are separated by a single blank line.

From [Wikipedia (blank line)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28text_file%29):

> A blank line usually refers to a line containing zero characters (not counting any end-of-line characters); though it may also refer to any line that does not contain any visible characters (consisting only of whitespace).

If you believe the Wikipedia definition, you might ask why zero characters is preferred.

For one it's simpler, even if autoindent is turned on in your editor, you're just filling your file with extra bytes for no good reason.

Second, a regex for a zero character blank line is simpler as well, '^$' usually vs something like '^\s*$'.

As other answers have pointed out, it makes no difference execution wise to put in whitespace. With no good reason to do so, I would say the best practice is to leave it out and keep it simple. Can you imagine a situation where a zero character line would be treated differently than a line with some whitespace? I would hate to program in that language. Putting in whitespace seems baroque to me.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to code execution it makes absolutely zero difference; the practice I have seen the most in python IS the one with white spaces, but I don't think anyone can really reasonably say one is objectively better than the other.

Answer (score 2):

As @PinkElephantsOnParade writes, it makes no difference for the execution. Thus, it's solely a matter of personal aesthetical preference.

I myself set my editor to display trailing whitespace, since I think trailing whitespace is a bad idea. Thus, your line 10 would be highlighted and stare me in the face all the time.
Nobody wants that, so I'd argue line 10 should not contain whitespace. (Which, coincidentally is how my editor, emacs, handles this automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

To each his own, but one way to look at it is: code style is about human readability. Therefore, trailing white-space is only an issue if it extends the length of the line past some preexisting (self-imposed) limit (ex. 80 char limit).

On the other hand, if you consistently display white-space in your editor, and this matters to you, I personally would keep it there, as it would be (for some, at least) more efficient to have the white-space present; if you decide to add code at that line at some point, you won't have to add additional white-space.